# Alternative of regex to hide matching id elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id=plan>
  <div id="plan-1" class='plan-hide'>One</div>
  <div id="plan-2" class='plan-hide'>Two</div>
  <div id="plan-3">Three</div>
  <div id="plan-4" class='plan-hide'>Four</div>
</div>
```

I want to hide all the plans (plan-1, plan-2, plan-3, plan-4) in the `#plan`

I have used regex `[id^=plan-]` but I believe its slow.

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 4
}, {
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("[id^=plan-]").addClass('plan-hide');
        $("#plan-" + (ui.value+1)).removeClass('plan-hide');
    },
});
```

What is alternative way?

Comment: It's not really a regex, it's a jQuery "starts-with" selector, but it could be it's using regex behind the scenes, and it probably is a lot slower than just selecting by the entire ID. Doing this in the "slide" callback will fire the adding/removing of classes on every increment of the slider, which makes it even slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to add the class to all the elements in the container except the one that matches the ui value + 1, targeting all siblings is probably faster:

```
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#plan-" + (ui.value+1)).removeClass('plan-hide')
                                  .siblings().addClass('plan-hide');
    },
```

or even just:

```
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#plan').children('div').addClass('plan-hide');
        $("#plan-" + (ui.value+1)).removeClass('plan-hide');
    },
```

and probably fastest:

```
var elems = document.getElementById('plan').getElementsByTagName('div'),    
    len = elems.length;

$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 4
}, {
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
            elems[i].className = elems[i].id.indexOf(ui.value+1) != -1 ? '' : 'plan-hide';
        }
    },
});
​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parent id plan to shorten the scope of element being matched.

```
$('#plan [id^=plan-]').addClass('plan-hide');
```